# dojo 1.9 dojox/widget/Rotator for image dynamically

Tags: javascript, image, dojo, slideshow, pojo

dojox.widget.Rotator is very old in DojoToolkit 1.9. Seems there is no any update.

I tried to create a image widget rotator by using dojoToolkit 1.9. but I can do it as seems there is no way to do it in dojo 1.9.

From dojo documentation, some thing like:

```
dojo.require("dojox.widget.Rotator");
dojo.require("dojox.widget.rotator.Fade");
dojo.ready(function(){
// add a 3rd pane
dojo.create("div", { className: "pane", innerHTML: "dynamically added Pane" }, "myRotator2");

new dojox.widget.Rotator(
    {
        transition: "dojox.widget.rotator.fade"
    },
    dojo.byId("myRotator2")
  );
});
```

It is totally <1.7 style, does any one have an example for dojo 1.9?

I need it to generate a widget rotator from POJO (get from database.)

I tried some thing like this:

```
require(["dojo/dojo","dojo/dom","dojo/request/xhr","dojo/_base/array","dojo/_base/json","dojo/dom-construct","dojo/_base/connect", "dojox/widget/Rotator", "dojox/widget/rotator/Fade","dojo/domReady!"], function(dojo,dom,xhr,array,json,domConst){
var dataJson = {siteId:siteId};
var imgholdernode = dom.byId("imgholder");
/*imgholdernode.innerHTML = siteId;*/
xhr("getFileMinisByCustomerNSite",{
    handleAs: "json",
    query:dataJson,
}).then(function(data){
    if (data.length>0){
        var imgRotator = new dojox.widget.Rotator({id:"imgRotator",transition: "dojox.widget.rotator.fade"});
        domConst.place(imgRotator,imgholdernode);
        array.forEach(data,function(item,i){
            domConst.create("img", {"className": "pane","id": item.fileId, "src": "data:"+item.fileType+";base64,"+item.thumbnail}, "imgRotator");
        });
        domConst.create("button",{"onclick":"connect.publish('imgRotator/rotator/control',[prev]);",innerHTML: "Prev",type: "button"});
        domConst.create("button",{"onclick":"connect.publish('imgRotator/rotator/control',[next]);",innerHTML: "Next",type: "button"});
        /*imgholdernode.innerHTML = data.length;*/
    }else{
        imgholdernode.innerHTML = "No image available.";
    }
  });
});
```

But it never works for me. Any one has experience, please share with me!

Comment: On dojo demo website, it seems to be AMD. See http://demos.dojotoolkit.org/dojox/widget/tests/test_Rotator.html

Comment: @ben. Thank you! Is there any reference source code available? I need some source code to test it.

Comment: is it what you mean ?: https://github.com/dojo/dojox/blob/master/widget/tests/test_Rotator.html

Comment: Thank you for your advice, Hope it will works for me. Have a good weekend!